# trim json based on matching keys using python

Tags: python, json

I have a JSON in which I am trying to trim if a certain criteria is matched. Below is my JSON:

```
{'Items': [
    {'type': 'track', 'event': 'flag', 'properties': {'old': 'ABC11001'
        }, 'options': {'target': 'unflag'
        }, 'userId': None, 'anonymousId': 'c7ccc67e-f7d4-4198-9cef-7d6895c1bd3b', 'meta': {'timestamp': 1603043772959
        }, '_': {'originalAction': 'track', 'called': 'track', 'from': 'engineEnd'
        }, 'traits': {'lfid': 'foobar'
        }, 'id': '40cfb8a0-116b-11eb-9635-df40a485d353', 'id': 'footer', 'partner_resid': '934591a0-e05d-dd62-a55a-sh1735ec3981'
    },
    {'type': 'track', 'event': 'next', 'properties': {'old': 'ABC110023', 'new': 'ABC110026'
        }, 'options': {'target': 'nextTop'
        }, 'userId': None, 'anonymousId': 'c7ccc67e-f7d4-4198-9cef-7d6895c1bd3b', 'meta': {'timestamp': 1603043943118
        }, '_': {'originalAction': 'track', 'called': 'track', 'from': 'engineEnd'
        }, 'traits': {'lfid': 'foobar'
        }, 'id': 'a63ab410-116b-11eb-83a1-99c63d9410bc', 'lfid': 'foobar', 'partner_resid': '934591a0-e05d-dd62-a55a-sh1735ec3981'
    },
    {'type': 'track', 'event': 'flag', 'properties': {'old': 'ABC110099'
        }, 'options': {'target': 'unflag'
        }, 'userId': None, 'anonymousId': 'c7ccc67e-f7d4-4198-9cef-7d6895c1bd3b', 'meta': {'timestamp': 1603043137542
        }, '_': {'originalAction': 'track', 'called': 'track', 'from': 'engineEnd'
        }, 'traits': {'lfid': 'foobar'
        }, 'id': 'c6116880-1169-11eb-9880-c39a5007644a', 'lfid': 'foobar', 'partner_resid': '934591a0-e05d-dd62-a55a-sh1735ec3981'
    },
    {'type': 'track', 'event': 'flag', 'properties': {'new': 'ABC002234'
        }, 'options': {'target': 'flag'
        }, 'userId': None, 'anonymousId': 'c7ccc67e-f7d4-4198-9cef-7d6895c1bd3b', 'meta': {'timestamp': 1603042870105
        }, '_': {'originalAction': 'track', 'called': 'track', 'from': 'engineEnd'
        }, 'traits': {'lfid': 'foobar'
        }, 'id': '26a94d80-1169-11eb-9880-c39a5007644a', 'lfid': 'foobar', 'partner_resid': '934591a0-e05d-dd62-a55a-sh1735ec3981'
    },
    {'type': 'track', 'event': 'active', 'properties': {'new': 'ABC883322'
        }, 'options': {'target': 'bottomNext'
        }, 'userId': None, 'anonymousId': 'c7ccc67e-f7d4-4198-9cef-7d6895c1bd3b', 'meta': {'timestamp': 1603037276643
        }, '_': {'originalAction': 'track', 'called': 'track', 'from': 'engineEnd'
        }, 'traits': {'lfid': 'foobar'
        }, 'id': '20b1aab0-115c-11eb-9e18-b5713e730a08', 'lfid': 'foobar', 'partner_resid': '958791a0-e05d-4e01-a55a-da48e3ec3981'
    },
  }
```

Here I am trying to filter with `event` having `active` and `properties` with only `new` But failing to produce:
Below is my code:

```
    for idx, elem in enumerate(json_result['Items']):
        
        if json_result.get("Items").get("elem").properties.get("old") in elem.keys():
            del json_result['Items'][idx]
```

Not sure where I am doing wrong

`result_json` should contain only:

```
        {'type': 'track', 'event': 'active', 'properties': {'new': 'ABC883322'
            }, 'options': {'target': 'bottomNext'
            }, 'userId': None, 'anonymousId': 'c7ccc67e-f7d4-4198-9cef-7d6895c1bd3b', 'meta': {'timestamp': 1603037276643
            }, '_': {'originalAction': 'track', 'called': 'track', 'from': 'engineEnd'
            }, 'traits': {'lfid': 'foobar'
            }, 'id': '20b1aab0-115c-11eb-9e18-b5713e730a08', 'lfid': 'foobar', 'partner_resid': '958791a0-e05d-4e01-a55a-da48e3ec3981'}
```

Comment: One thing is that you don’t check that the ‘event’ key has value ‘active’.

Comment: I am pretty sure the `if` statement doesn't do what you want it to do...  the code is trying to access the sub-dictionary `properties` by attribute via `elem.properties` which will not exist because you can't access dictionary keys by attribute in Python.  The correct way of doing this is by index `elem["properties"]` or via `elem.get("properties")`.  Another issue is at the end the statement. It is checking if the value assigned to `elem["properties"]["old"]` is in `elem.keys()` but given the examples you have provided us this will never happen

Answer (score 1):

you do have a mistake in your json (missing closing list bracket) --> if I understand correctly you want to filter only those objects from json list that have `event=active` and key `"new" in properties`. Why not to create new result list and store there only matching objects.

```py
items = dct["Items"]
result = []
for obj in items:
    if obj["event"] == "active" and "new" in obj["properties"]:
        result.append(obj)
```